# Best way to take the content from an LI tag and copy it elsewhere?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to take content from a list (but not including the LI tag wrapped around it) and copy it elsewhere.

I've got this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/u5tFb/

I simply cannot figure this out. How do I get this working right?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
</div>

<ul>
   <li><p>Text 1</p><em>Text 2</em></li>
   <li>Gonna copy me too?</li>
   <li><h3>We're gonna be in DIVs!</h3></li>
</ul>

<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<button id="clear">Clear DIV</button>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    background: #eee;
}

#container .special {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#copy').click(function() {
    $('li').each(function(i) {
        $(this).clone().contents().wrap('<div class="special" />').appendTo('#container');
    });
});
```

jQuery:

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: Err, isn't it working the way it's supposed to it?

Comment: @Amit: No, it's not putting in the wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you're assuming [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) returns the wrapper. It's a perfectly reasonable assumption, but it's incorrect; it returns the original elements, not the wrapper. So when you append them, it's as though you hadn't put them in a wrapper, as the elements are moved out of it and the wrapper is thrown away.

I suspect this is more what you're looking for:

```
$('#copy').click(function() {
    $('li').each(function(i) {
        $("<div class='special'>")
            .append($(this).clone().contents())
            .appendTo('#container');
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5tFb/5/)

Though it would be *marginally* more efficient to use `$(this).contents().clone()` rather than `$(this).clone().contents()` since you don't use the cloned wrapper `li`, just the cloned contents:

```
$('#copy').click(function() {
    $('li').each(function(i) {
        $("<div class='special'>")
            .append($(this).contents().clone())
            .appendTo('#container');
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5tFb/7/)

Either way, those put the two elements in your first `li` in *one* wrapper `div`, which I suspect is what you want. Alternately, though, if you really want to wrap each part of what's in each `li` *separately*, just move up to the parent element before doing your final append (but that splits out *every* element in *each* `li` into its own `div`, which I don't think is what you want):

```
$('#copy').click(function() {
    $('li').each(function(i) {
        $(this)
            .clone()
            .contents()
            .wrap('<div class="special" />')
            .parent()  // <=== The new bit
            .appendTo('#container');
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5tFb/6/)

Comment: Sweet, thanks a ton! Makes total sense now. Another way to do it would be (within the $.each() loop): $(this).contents().clone().appendTo('#container').wrapAll('<div class="special" />') which, to me, is a little more readable due to the chain order.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack: True -- although it's more DOM operations. But unless there are a *lot* of them, that doesn't really matter.